# Adding specific ticks on top of defaults

Tags: python, bokeh

I want to ensure a couple of specific ticks are visible on the X axis **on top of the default ticks** of the plot. To this end [I found in the documentation](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/tickers.html) FixedTicker which allows me to specify exact values along the X axis where ticks should reside. However, if I set:

```
p.xaxis.ticker = FixedTicker(ticks=[-1,1])
```

...this replaces all tickers along the X axis with just the two I specified (one at -1 and one at 1). I tried "extending" the existing ticker using CompositeTicker:

```
# compose whatever is there by default, adding the fixed points:
p.xaxis.ticker = CompositeTicker(tickers=[p.xaxis.ticker, FixedTicker(ticks=[-1,1])])
```

This again does not seem to do what I need. The result is the same (I get an X axis with just two ticks at positions -1 and 1) as for using the plain FixedTicker. It's as if there is no 'composition' going on. Reading the documentation it does seem that CompositeTicker is more than a "sum of individual tickers" because I read:

> A list of Ticker objects to combine at different scales in order to generate tick values. The supplied tickers should be in order. Specifically, if S comes before T, then it should be the case that: `S.get_max_interval() < T.get_min_interval()`

How would one go about having a default "linear" ticker across whatever data range is in the column data source, but just "highlighting" a couple of point (which may or may not be present in the default ticker).

A simple use case would be for example plotting a quadratic function and highlighting its roots on the X axis.

Comment: What does "This again does not seem to do what I need." actually mean, exactly?

Comment: I've clarified the result and referenced the documentation. I think what I need is either not possible, or needs something "other than tickers"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it is *possible*, but it is not currently built-in. And "ticker" is the right concept, as a ticker is what decides what tick locations should be. However, as you have learned the `CompositeTicker` is for picking one "best" ticker (out of many possible) for the current scale (i.e pick nice days on a scale of months, pick nice months on a scale of years). To "join" two tickers like you want would require creating a [custom extension](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/extensions.html), which unfortunately at present involves a *lot* of boilerplate. Here is a reference version that works with Bokeh 1.4.0 <sup>***1***</sup>

```py
from bokeh.core.properties import Float, List
from bokeh.models import BasicTicker
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.util.compiler import TypeScript

TS_CODE = """
import * as p from "core/properties"
import {TickSpec} from "models/tickers/ticker"
import {BasicTicker} from "models/tickers/basic_ticker"

export namespace MyTicker {
  export type Attrs = p.AttrsOf<Props>
  export type Props = BasicTicker.Props & {
    extra_ticks: p.Property<Array<number>>
  }
}

export interface MyTicker extends MyTicker.Attrs {}

export class MyTicker extends BasicTicker {
  properties: MyTicker.Props

  constructor(attrs?: Partial<MyTicker.Attrs>) {
    super(attrs)
  }

  get_ticks_no_defaults(data_low: number, data_high: number, cross_loc: any, desired_n_ticks: number): TickSpec<number> {
    const ticks = super.get_ticks_no_defaults(data_low, data_high, cross_loc, desired_n_ticks)
    for (var i=0; i<this.extra_ticks.length; i++) {
      const et = this.extra_ticks[i]
      if (et >= data_low && et <= data_high)
        ticks.major.push(et)
    }
    return ticks
  }

  static init_MyTicker(): void {
    this.define<MyTicker.Props>({
      extra_ticks: [ p.Any ],
    })
  }
}
"""


class MyTicker(BasicTicker):
    __implementation__ = TypeScript(TS_CODE)
    extra_ticks = List(Float)


p = figure()
p.circle([1, 2, 3, 4, 6], [5, 7, 3, 2, 4], size=20)

p.xaxis.ticker = MyTicker(extra_ticks=[3.65])
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = 1.2

show(p)
```

Note that I have rotated the ticks as well since the extra tick does not participate in the calculations to keep ticks "spread apart" so they may overlap otherwise.

[image]

A "joined" ticker might be a reasonable feature request, as well as a nice task for a new contributor. Please feel free to open a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/issues) to suggest.

---

<sup>***1***</sup> Please note that BokehJS is still under very active development. Although its API is now reaching a level of stability, we do not yet make guarantees about custom extension compatibility version to version.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to write such a detailed answer. Taking into account that this example uses "unstable API", I will rather use a workaround I have found (I add a couple of Labels at locations along the X axis, plotting circles at the related points) and raise an issue to see if it gains traction. I do think it would be useful to others if the ability to further customize ticks was available.